# Why the lua function io.write() did not work. It only display the results on the terminal, rather than writing to a file

Tags: lua

I am learning the Lua IO library. I'm having trouble with io.write(). In Programming Design in Lua, there is a piece of code that iterates through the file line by line and precedes each line with a serial number.
This is the file I`m working on:

[test file: "iotest.txt"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKyXK.png)

This is my code

```
io.input("iotest.txt")
-- io.output("iotest.txt")
local count = 0
for line in io.lines() do
    count=count+1
    io.write(string.format("%6d ",count), line, "\n")
end
```

This is the result of the terminal display, but this result cannot be written to the file, whether I add IO. Output (" iotest.txt ") or not.

[the results in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKyXK.png)

This is the result of file, we can see there is no change

[The result after code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdtly.png)

Comment: You can not use the same file for both `io.input` and `io.output`

Comment: sorry, I'm a beginner in Lua, I know it should use file handles to operate mutiple file. but i`m confued about the code i have given.  when i use your code, the file "iotest.txt" will be cleared. And do you mean Lua does not allow Input and output not be the same file?@Piglet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `io.flush()` after your write operations to save the data to the file.

```
io.input("iotest.txt")
io.output("iotestout.txt")
local count = 0
for line in io.lines() do
    count=count+1
    io.write(string.format("%6d ",count), line, "\n")
end
io.flush()
io.close()
```

Refer to [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual : 6.8 - Input and Output Facilities](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.8)

`io.flush()` will save any written data to the output file which you set with `io.output`

See koyaanisqatsi's answer for the optional use of file handles. This becomes especially useful if you're working on multiple files at a time and gives you more control on how to interact with the file.

That said you should also have different files for input and output. You'll agree that it doesn't make sense to read and write from and to the same file alternatingly.

Comment: sorry, I'm a beginner in Lua, I know it should use file handles to operate mutiple file. but i`m confued about the code i have given.  when i use your code, the file "iotest.txt" will be cleared.

Comment: sorry I didn't realize your using the same file. see edit. you're creating an empty buffer for the input file when you set it as output file so you're not reading anything and hence write an empty file.

Comment: thank you for your answer. And do you mean Lua does not allow Input and output not be the same file?

Answer (score 0):

For writing to a file you need a file handle.
This handle comes from: `io.open()`
See: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.8
A file handle has methods that acts on self.
Thats the function after the `:` at file handle.
So `io.write()` puts out on `stdout`  and `file:write()` in a file.

Example function that can dump a defined function to a file...

```
fdump=function(func,path)
assert(type(func)=="function")
assert(type(path)=="string")
-- Get the file handle (file)
local file,err = io.open(path, "wb")
assert(file, err)
local chunk = string.dump(func,true)
file:write(chunk)
file:flush()
file:close()
return 'DONE'
end
```

Here are the methods, taken from `io.stdin`

```
close = function: 0x566032b0
seek = function: 0x566045f0
flush = function: 0x56603d10
setvbuf = function: 0x56604240
write = function: 0x56603e70
lines = function: 0x566040c0
read = function: 0x56603c90
```

This makes it able to use it directly like...
( Lua console: lua -i )

```
> do io.stdout:write('Input: ') local result=io.stdin:read() return result end
Input: d
d
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open the same file for reading and writing at the same time. You cannot do that.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Read from file X, iterate through it and write the result to another file Y.
2. Read the complete file X into memory, close file X, then delete file X, open the same filename for writing and write to it while iterating through the original file (in memory).

Otherwise, your approach is correct although file operations in Lua are more often done using io.open() and file handles instead of io.write() and io.read().