# Script creates a txt but doesnt write anything in there lua

Tags: string, file, lua, timer

I made a script that uses a prefix (.) to identify a command. My command is .timeset. If the user enters numbers after the .timeset it should separate these values into days hours mins and secs. It uses a space to identify these. After identifying them it should write them into a file. The next step is to read the file and calculate the days hours mins and secs into seconds(My timer uses seconds) and write the total amount into a new file. But it isn't working correctly (doesn't write the input from the user into the file). I hope you guys can help me!
Code:

```
function readFile(file)
    local lines = io.lines(file)
    local result = {}
    
    for line in lines do 
        table.insert(result, line)
    end
    return result
end

function writeFile(file, text)
    wrFile = io.open(file, "w")
    io.output(wrFile)
    io.write(text)
    io.close(wrFile)
end


command = "timeset"
help_message = "Set your Timer! Format: Days Hours Minutes Seconds"

function execute(arguments)
 local args = ""
    for word in string.gmatch(arguments, "[^%s]+") do
        string.insert(args, word)
            writeFile("timerset.txt", word)
            f = io.open("timerset.txt", "r")
            io.input(f)
            dayst = f:read("*line")
            hourst = f:read("*line")
            mint = f:read("*line")
            sect = f:read("*line")
            resultTime = dayst + hourst + mint + sect
            f:close()
            dayst = dayst *86400
            hourst = hourst *3600
            mint = mint *60
            resultTime = dayst + hourst + mint + sect
            writeFile("timerset.txt", resultTime)
            end
       end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the lua function io.write() did not work. It only display the results on the terminal, rather than writing to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67251018/why-the-lua-function-io-write-did-not-work-it-only-display-the-results-on-the)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua script sometimes doesn't save values in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212002/lua-script-sometimes-doesnt-save-values-in-the-file)

Comment: @Piglet my old script worked without io.flush... Because io.close also flushes the data into the file and io.flush isnt needed

Comment: @IvoBeckers It doesn't solve my problem it is the string splitting part (99 percent sure)

Comment: how is this code being executed? as is it just defines a few functions and variables. what is `arguments`?  also note that instead of `[^%s]` you can simply write `%S`. what is `string.insert`?

Comment: fixed what? I don't see any changes. your post has not been edited yet